# WooCommerce show some attributes when selected previous option

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have a problem when selecting a specific attribute all other items are shown. I only want to show the items related to the previous item Example :
[image]

when selected "Carree"  Show : 100*100 and 120*120 and 60*60 and 80*80
When selected "Portraits" Show : 100*150 and 120*80 and 60*90

[image]